# Puzzle & Golf : Reproduce this gif

Tags: code-golf, geometry

The objective of this programming puzzle is to reproduce the following gif.
[image]

Simplification: If you notice the geometric figures don't exactly touch each other. I think it's simpler if you make each vertex to touch the respective edge, and not to go beyond it. I'm not sure though of how this will alter the configuration of the balls movement.

Specifications: Sizes, colours, etc. Make them to your heart's content. But let's just be reasonable. I would prefer if the velocity of the balls was slower than that in the gif.
For those who are having a harder time understanding the picture, we begin with a triangle (3 sides), then a square(4sides), then a pentagon(5sides), and so on... until an pentadecagon (15 sides).

Wining condition: Smallest solution wins.

Berserker Mode: Do the gif by adding a third dimension...

Comment: Can you include the gif/example image into the post. I shouldn't have to go to a third party site to know what I should be doing. Also what does `Berserker Mode: Do the gif by adding a third dimension...` mean? Can you add some specifics, size, colour, radius of each "circle", speed of the dots, how many sides each "circle" has etc?

Comment: The biggest problem is that the winning condition is unclear. You could fix that by adding a [tag:code-golf] tag so that the shortest solution wins. In this case the berserker mode could grant a bonus to the byte count, but I think  it would be better to keep it for another challenge.

Comment: VTC as unclear because, as it stands, it lacks any sepcifications for the individual elements. Tip: Throw this into the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/58974) and people will help you flesh it out.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder done the gif.